# Grid only creating one box instead of a 16x16 grid

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm setting up a grid that can be tapped to change colours (like a litebrite). However, it's not creating the whole grid, only one box.

Here's an image of the current output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1Uxw.jpg

```
for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
    for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
        BoxView box = new BoxView
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                Color = borderColor,
            };
        /*  add code create TapGestureRecognizer entry */
        var tap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        box.GestureRecognizers.Add(tap);
        tap.Tapped += OnBoxViewTapped;
        //  Add the current box to the boxes list
        boxes.Add(box); 
        //  Add the current box to the mainGrid
        mainGrid.Children.Add(box); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please do not post *images* of code or output. In order to get the best responses and feedback, please copy/paste your output into your **question post**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify row and col when adding to the Grid, otherwise every child will be on top of each other at 0,0

```
mainGrid.Children.Add(box,row,col);
```